Separability of functional space
Perhaps the discussion of my question is too specific. So, let me make it more general.
Consider a set of functions $q:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ represented as $q(\mathbf{k})$ where $\mathbf{k}\in\mathbb{R}^3$. These functions have a finite $L^2$ norm
$$ \|q\|^2 = \int |q(\mathbf{k})|^2 d^k < \infty . $$
Let's denote this set by $\mathcal{Q}$.
Now I define a set of functionals as $\psi:\mathcal{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, each denoted by $\psi[q]$. These functionals are all normalized so that the functional integral over the modulus square of the functional gives
$$ \|\psi\|^2 = \int |\psi[q]|^2 \mathcal{D}[q] = 1 , $$
where $\mathcal{D}[q]$ represents the functional integration measure.[note 1] However, for the sake of the discussion we can relax this requirement to say that they have a finite $L^2$ norm.
The set of all such functionals forms a normed vector space, so we can look for a basis for this space. The question is: would such a basis be countable? In other words, is this functional space separable? Even if a definitive answer cannot be provided, any useful information that can illuminate the issue raised by the question would be very welcome. Any links to accessible literature on the topics would also be appreciated.

For a more specific context:
Let $\hat{q}$ be an unbounded Hermitian operator on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_?$. [note 2] It is defined as an operator valued function on $\mathbb{R}^3$. I'll represent it as $\hat{q}(\mathbf{k})$ where $\mathbf{k}\in\mathbb{R}^3$. (I'll try to use correct mathematical notation, but not being a mathematician, I may get it wrong. Please be patient with me.) An eigenvalue equation for $\hat{q}$ is given by
$$ \hat{q}(\mathbf{k})|q\rangle = |q\rangle q(\mathbf{k}) , $$
where I use Dirac notation to represent the eigenvectors $|q\rangle$ and $q(\mathbf{k})$ is an eigenvalue function $q:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. In the equation, the dependence on $\mathbf{k}$ is transferred from the operator to the eigenvalue, but the eigenstates do not explicitly depend on $\mathbf{k}$. The eigenvalue function turn out to be functions with a finite $L^2$-norm, $q\in \mathcal{Q}=L^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$. So, according to my understanding the space of all these eigenvalue functions is separable.
For each $q\in \mathcal{Q}$ there is a unique eigenstates $|q\rangle$. In other words, the eigenvectors are parameterized by the eigenvalue functions. These eigenvectors are not normalizable, but they are mutually orthogonal
$$ \langle q|q'\rangle = \delta[q-q'] , $$
where the $\delta[q-q']$ is the Dirac delta functional; [note 3] the square brackets indicate that the argument contains functions. The eigenvectors can also resolve the identity of the space on which $\hat{q}$ is defined. It is represented by functional integral over the space $\mathcal{Q}$, as
$$ \int |q\rangle\langle q| \mathcal{D}[q] = \mathbb{I} . $$
Therefore, we can use the eigenvectors as a basis in terms of which we can define arbitrary states
$$ |\psi\rangle = \int |q\rangle\psi[q] \mathcal{D}[q] , $$
where $\psi[q]:\mathcal{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. These states form a Hilbert space $|\psi\rangle\in\mathcal{H}\subset\mathcal{H}_?$. They would be normalized provided that the functional $\psi[q]$ is normalized so that
$$ \|\psi\|^2 = \int |\psi[q]|^2 \mathcal{D}[q] = 1 . $$
The space of all such functionals $\psi[q]$ thus represents all the states $|\psi\rangle$; it is isomorphic to $\mathcal{H}$. However, the eigenvectors do not belong to this Hilbert space $|q\rangle\notin\mathcal{H}$ because they are not normalizable (they do not have a finite $L^2$ norm).
Question: Is $\mathcal{H}$ (the space of all the functionals $\psi[q]$ thus defined) separable?

[note 1] The exact definition of the functional integration measure is not known. The best I can do is to specify that the functional integration of a Gaussian functional produces a specific form for the result corresponding to the equivalent for a finite dimensional Gaussian function.
[note 2] Apart from being infinite dimensional (and probably inseparable) the nature of this Hilbert space is unknown. We can specify that it contains a vacuum state $|\text{vac}\rangle$ with a property that $\hat{a}|\text{vac}\rangle=0$, where $\hat{a}$ is an element of the algebra in terms of which $\hat{q}$ is defined. Then we build up all the other elements in this Hilbert space from $|\text{vac}\rangle$ through applications of the algebra.
[note 3] It really comes out to be a Dirac delta functional as I've shown in PRA 98/043841 (and its erratum PRA 101/019903).

I have a few questions/comments.
What does $\mathcal D[q]$ mean? No $\mathcal D$ was introduced… In your explanation of the specific context, you're saying $\hat q$ is an an operator, so on what space is it acting? Same question for the values of $\hat q$: you're saying $\hat q$ is an operator-valued function, so on what space(s) are the values of $\hat q$ acting? What does eigenstate mean? Is it really the Dirac delta you want to use here? It doesn't make much sense right now. And finally: what does normalizable mean?

@P.P.Tuong, thanks for the comments and questions. I'll try to address them.

@P.P.Tuong Please see the edited version with the notes provided at the bottom. I change "eigenstates" to "eigenvectors." Please let me know if there are more questions.
